# Show $\|f\|_{C[0,1]} \leq C \|f\|_{H^1[0,1]}$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

My question:

If $f \in C^1[0,1]$, show that $\|f\|_C[0,1] \leq C\|f\|_{H^1[0,1]}$, where $C$ is a constant independent of $f$ and $\|f\|^2_{H^1[0,1]}:= \|f\|^2_{L^2[0,1]}+\|f'\|^2_{L^2[0,1]}$.

Unfortunately I've made no progress on this so far on this so I can't report on my work. A hint to get me started is all I'm asking for here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** notice that by the FTC we have $$|f(x)| \le |f(y)| + \int_y^x|f'(t)|\,dt \le |f(y)| + \int_0^1|f'(t)|\,dt.$$

Comment: Ah! why couldn't I just see this in the first place. I should be able to finish off the problem now.

Comment: I am glad I could help :)